# How to get Expess object cookie in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, cookies

[Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) says that we can set a cookie with an object using this function:

```
res.cookie('cart', { items: [1,2,3] });
```

I want to retrieve this value using [Angular ngCookie](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies):

```
var cart= $cookies.getObject('cart');
```

But it throw an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token j
```

I can retrieve the string value of the cookie using `$cookie.get('cart')`, and, indeed, it looks like this:

```
j:{ "items": [1,2,3] }
```

I know I can remove the characters and then parse the object, but I'd rather have a more generic method.

**Can I force Express to not set the cookie with this syntax (without "j:")?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make JSON-string manually:

```
res.cookie('cart', JSON.stringify({ items: [1,2,3] }) );
```

Prefix `j:` added in `./express/lib/response.js` (lines 787-789):

```
var val = typeof value === 'object'
    ? 'j:' + JSON.stringify(value)
    : String(value);
```

where `value` is your object `{ items: [1,2,3] }`

> It's not part of any standard, as the RFC for cookies says the value   can only be a string. Ideally if we followed the standard, we would reject your cookie if it wasn't a string. As a convenience, Express.js allows you to set non-strings as the values, and we'll JSON.stringify the value, pre-pending a j: so we know the value should be JSON.parsed when we read it again for you.

https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2815

Comment: Why I didn't think about that...so obvious! :) Thanks. I don't accept your answer now, in case of anyone know why express use this notation...